# Почему меню не доступно?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Вопрос! Почему меню не доступно? Visual Studio 2010

[image: Почему меню не доступно? Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: Колонка типа varchar?

Comment: @Suvitruf nchar(10)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446596/unable-to-change-identity-specification-to-yes-in-sql-server-table

Comment: Identity колонку вроде как нельзя поменять, если она строковая. Она типа `int` должна быть.

Comment: @Suvitruf пытаюсь поменять значения в других колонках - но не доступно, нельзя поменять. В чем дело?

Comment: Я с sql в Студии не работаю. Максимум что могу посоветовать - это в вопросе по ссылке ответы почитать )=

Comment: @Suvitruf Где находиться AUTO_INCREMENT?